# Output difference in expected result

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data input like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), stocks = c("google stock, yahoo product stock", "google stock, yahoo product stock","amazon, yahoo product","yahoo product, amazon","yahoo product stock", "google stock"))
```

I expected to take a result like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), stocks = c("google stock, yahoo product stock", "google stock, yahoo product stock","amazon, yahoo product stock","yahoo product stock, amazon","yahoo product stock", "google stock"))
                              combination frequency
    1 google stock - yahoo product stock       2
    2        amazon - yahoo product stock         2
    3                 yahoo product stock         1
    4                        google stock         1
```

I tried this:

```
library(tidyverse)
 df %>%
     separate_rows(stocks, sep = ",") %>%
     full_join(df %>%
                   separate_rows(stocks), by = c("id" = "id")) %>%
     filter(stocks.x != stocks.y) %>%
     count(stocks.x, stocks.y) %>%
     transmute(stocks = paste(pmax(stocks.x, stocks.y), pmin(stocks.x, stocks.y), sep = "-"),
               n) %>%
     distinct(stocks, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

but I receive this results

> ```
> # A tibble: 16 x 2
>    stocks                           n
>    <chr>                        <int>
>  1 amazon- yahoo product            2
>  2 product- yahoo product           2
>  3 yahoo- yahoo product             2
>  4 google- yahoo product stock      2
>  5 product- yahoo product stock     2
>  6 stock- yahoo product stock       4
>  7 yahoo- yahoo product stock       2
>  8 product-amazon                   2
>  9 yahoo-amazon                     2
> 10 google stock-google              3
> 11 product-google stock             2
> 12 stock-google stock               5
> 13 yahoo-google stock               2
> 14 yahoo product stock-product      1
> 15 yahoo product stock-stock        1
> 16 yahoo product stock-yahoo        1
> ```

Using `table()` is not the optimal solution for my case as my real dataset more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this (below). If so, I will annotate each step. Basically it splits your string based on the comma, cleans up white space, sorts the split pieces, collapses them together with " - ", and the uses `dpylr` functions to get the counts. I made a lot of assumptions so let me know if it does not work for you. Also, this may be faster to do in `data.table` [depending on the number of groups](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-:-Grouping), but I stuck with `dplyr` because that is what you used. Good luck!!

```
split_stock <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$stocks), ",", fixed = T), function(x) sort(trimws(x)))

df1$stocks2 <- sapply(split_stock, paste0, collapse = " - ")

df1 %>%
  group_by(stocks2) %>%
  count() %>%
  arrange(desc(n))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  stocks2                                n
  <chr>                              <int>
1 amazon - yahoo product                 2
2 google stock - yahoo product stock     2
3 google stock                           1
4 yahoo product stock                    1
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), stocks = c("google stock, yahoo product stock", "google stock, yahoo product stock","amazon, yahoo product","yahoo product, amazon","yahoo product stock", "google stock"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `full_join()`.

Use `separate_rows()` in order to identify all company `stocks` by `id`, then use `group_by()` / `summarise()` with the function `paste(collapse = ' ')` in order to concatenate the different possibility within your `stocks` variable. Finally, use `count()` for your need.

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(stocks) %>% 
  filter(!stocks %in% c('stock', 'product')) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(group_stocks = paste(sort(stocks), collapse = ' ')) %>% 
  count(group_stocks)

#   group_stocks     n
#   <chr>        <int>
# 1 amazon yahoo     2
# 2 google           1
# 3 google yahoo     2
# 4 yahoo            1
```